# PREG_REPLACE in MySQL and PREG_REPLACE_EVAL

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-replace

I'm using [this UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php) for the PREG_REPLACE function in MySQL and everything seems to be working fine so far. However, my goal now is to find and encode entities inside `pre` tags in a column. So ultimately I'd like to get this:

```
<pre>
    <strong>Hello World!</strong>
</pre>
```

To look like this:

```
<pre>
    &lt;strong&gt;Hello World!&lt;/strong&gt;
</pre>
```

I'm using the PREG_REPLACE function to find the contents inside the `pre` tags like this:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('/<pre>(.*?)<\\/pre>/sm', '\\1', '<pre><strong>Hello World</strong></pre>');
```

Now I'd like to replace `\\1` with something that would say "replace with `ENCODE_ENTITIES('\\1')`. Obviously it could be any other function, like `UPPER` for example, but `UPPER('\\1')` doesn't give much. I kind of like the idea of `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` in PHP's implementation of `preg_replace` which allows something like this:

```
preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e", 
    "'\\1'.strtoupper('\\2').'\\3'", 
    $html_body);
```

Any ideas on how to implement something similar in MySQL? Or maybe I'm heading the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure pre will not be nested with other pre elements?

Comment: @FailedDev yes I'm pretty sure, at least in my case, but you're right it's something we should watch out for. Thanks!

Comment: You can't watch out for it. If this is the case regex is not a good solution for this task. If you are 100% sure that pre elements would not contain other pre elements I could offer a solution to your current problem.

Comment: @FailedDev I'm certain, but note that I'm looking for a MySQL solution, not a Python script that would operate on an SQL dump ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to modify the source code for the UDF to add that feature, there's no way to do that in MySQL.  I suggest you pick your favorite programming language and write a program to make the update for you, or perhaps ensure that this modification is performed before the data hits the database.